# leaving 2-norm propelled probability implications

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, quantum-information

I am curious about why there are no further generalized probability structures used in Physics. The great revolution was moving away from one-norm system to a two-norm system. What happens if we attempt to generalize to some n-norm system and formulate discover some rule for appropriate representations. Is it possible to have similar physics in some limit? ps please try to reason with me here. 
 otherwise;

$P_{R} \rightarrow$ classical

$P_{C} \rightarrow$ Quantum

$P_{n} \rightarrow$  ?

I really don't know . . . .

Comment: Perhaps look up "Exercise 5 for the Non-Lazy Reader" in [this lecture](http://www.scottaaronson.com/democritus/lec9.html). Also ["Is Quantum Mechanics An Island In Theoryspace?"](http://www.scottaaronson.com/papers/island.pdf)

Comment: wow, it is exactly what i was looking for. Well I guess it won't be a fruitful way of searching for new physics